# how to count subgroups in BIRT

Tags: birt

I'm doing a report with BIRT 3.7 and I've a query order by customers and invoice, with a group for customer and subgroup for invoices. So the thing that I need is for each customer, how many invoices it has. I'm trying to use function count from Aggregation related to invoices's subgroup, but when I run the report, the aggregation variable shows the total of details from last invoice.
Any comment is welcome!.

Thanks.